# SAS Monthly Update

Tags: automation, sas

I have a dataset where there are 2 columns for the current month and the previous month. I need to perform a sum operation on these two columns only. The problem is with every monthly update the name of column changes. How can I automate this procedure in SAS?

Current Dataset

ID  Sep   Oct

1   23    12
2   31    19
3   37    21

Next Month Dataset

ID  Oct   Nov

1   17    21
2   12    23
3   55    21

How do I automate summation of the two columns every month?

Comment: What exactly you want the output of summary look like?

Answer (score 2):

If there's always three columns, the first being the ID, and the 2nd & 3rd being the values you wish to sum, use an array...

```
data mysum ;
  set mydata ;
  array n{*} _NUMERIC_ ; /* ID VAR1 VAR2 */

  /* sum 2nd & 3rd elements */
  month_sum = sum(n{2},n{3}) ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are aggregating columns:

```
proc sql noprint;
select
cat('sum(', trim(name), ') as month', put(monotonic(), 1. -L)) into :sum_statement separated  by ', '
from dictionary.columns
where libname = 'WORK'
and memname = 'SOMETABLE'
and upcase(name) ne 'ID'
;
quit;

%put &sum_statement;

proc sql;
create table sum as
select &sum_statement from WORK.SOMETABLE
;
quit;
```